# Asymptotic standard normal distribution

Tags: asymptotics, normal-distribution, characteristic-functions

I need to solve the following exercise.

> Assume that $X_\lambda$ is Poisson distributed with mean $\lambda$ . Show that $Y(\lambda) = \frac{X_\lambda - \lambda}{\sqrt{\lambda}}$ is asymptotic standard normal distributed for $\lambda \to \infty$.

Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: do you know the central limit theorem?

Comment: @tired I know that $E(Y)= 0$, $Var(Y) = 1$ and so the central limit theorem would tell us that $\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\cdot \sum\limits_{k=1}^{n} Y_{k}$ follows a standard normal distribution.

Comment: @tired I am confused about what $\lambda \to \infty $ means here.

Comment: @teotheo You mean std normal if $n \to \infty$ ?

Comment: The exerice says that $\lambda \to \infty$. Am i wrong about my first comment?

Comment: @teotheo You didn't tag us. Um, standard normal? '[In the case σ > 0, convergence in distribution means that the cumulative distribution functions of √n(Sn − µ) converge pointwise to the cdf of the N(0, σ2) distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_limit_theorem#Classical_CLT)'

Comment: @BCLCWell $\sqrt{n}(\frac{S_{n}}{n} - \mu)$ converges to $N(0,\sigma^2)$

Comment: @BCLCHere when i use $Y_k$ i mean the $Y$ defined on this exercise.

Comment: @teotheo In the end I kind of feel sorry for you, seeing the deadends user BCLC is trying to send you into. A standard approach to solve your question is to compute the characteristic functions $$\varphi_\lambda(x)=E(e^{ixX_\lambda}),$$ and to show that, for every fixed $x$, $$\varphi_\lambda(x)\to e^{-x^2/2}.$$ Since the RHS is the characteristic function of a standard normal distribution, Lévy's continuity theorem yields the desired convergence in distribution. So... do you meet any obstacle when computing $\varphi_\lambda$? I suggest to first compute $$\psi_\lambda(x)=E(e^{ixY(\lambda)}).$$

Comment: By the way, **you** included the tag (characteristic-functions), right?

Comment: @Did I managed to solve it by using at some point a taylor expansion of $e^x$.

Your advice was very helpful.

Comment: Great. Indeed, a Taylor expansion of the exponential comes into play. Since your question received no answer yet, you might want to post your solution as an answer and even, after a while, to accept it.

Answer (score -1):

Not quite sure if the one on Wiki is right or if I understand it, but anyway I'm basing my answer on CLT in Larsen and Marx (an *elementary* probability book):

[image]

---

Anyway, this answer might be weird or very wrong or stupid but...

Consider iid $X_i$ ~ $Poi(\lambda/n)$.

Then $X := \sum_{i=1}^{n} X_i$ ~ $Poi(\lambda)$

Then

$$(\frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^{n} X_i - \mu) / (\sigma/\sqrt{n})$$

$$= (\frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^{n} X_i - \lambda/n) / (\sqrt{\lambda}/n)$$

$$= (\sum_{i=1}^{n} X_i - \lambda) / (\sqrt{\lambda})$$

$$= Y(\lambda)$$

---

Now I'm thinking we have to come up w/ some kind of relationship between n and $\lambda$ s.t. as $n \to \infty$, $\lambda \to \infty$

---

Guess 1:

$$= (\sum_{i=1}^{(\frac{\lambda}{E[X_i]})} X_i - \lambda) / (\sqrt{\lambda})$$

I was thinking as $\lambda \to \infty \iff n \to \infty$ as $\lambda = n E[X_i]$ but then again $E[X_i]$ is a function of both n and $\lambda$

---

Guess 2:

$P(X_i = k) \ge 0 \to (\frac{\lambda}{n})^k \ge 0$

Not sure how to proceed. I guess $\exists a > 0$ s.t. $\lambda^k = a n^k$ ?

Comment: Do you think it could be that complicated? Could it be a typo in the formulation and instead of $\lambda\to\infty$ it should write $n\to\infty$?.

Comment: @teotheo Do you really find it complicated? I just wrote $X$ as a sum of other random variables. That is what you are supposed to do to apply CLT right? Just like w/ Binomial = sum Bernoulli? I think Guess 1 is wrong, but Guess 2 might be on to something. Even if it's not a typo, see guess 2 :P